# Convert a number to international, PHP

Tags: php, internationalization, string-formatting, phone-number

In PHP what is the quickest way to convert an mobile number to international format:

So 07123456789 becomes 447123456789.

I have tried a few ways and cant seem to get it to work.

This is current script:

```
    if(strlen($gsm) > 2) {
        if(!substr_compare($gsm, "07", 0, 2, false)) {
            unset($gsm);
        }
        elseif (substr_compare($gsm, "07", 0, 3, true)) {
            if(strlen($gsm) == 11) {
                return "447" . substr($gsm, 2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: This script only runs if the number matches a regex.

Comment: quick as in script execution time or lines / complexity of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$intl_number = preg_replace('/^0/','44',$uk_number);
```

or if you specifically only want to do UK mobile numbers:

```
$intl_number = preg_replace('/^07/','447',$uk_mob_number);
```

(note: I'm assuming UK-specific since you specified '44' in the question)

This does use Regex, but should be pretty quick in execution speed since it is anchored to the begining of the string.

Comment: slight typo:

$intl_number = preg_replace('/^07/,'447',$uk_mob_number); should be $intl_number = preg_replace('/^07/','447',$uk_mob_number);

Comment: @Kyle - d'oh. fixed. thanks. (easy to miss the odd quote mark when you don't have syntax highlighting and you're not actually running the code!)

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way that comes to mind for me, as long as you are shre the number matches the format 07xxxxxx at this point:

```
 $number = "07123456789";
 $number = '44'.substr($number,1);
```

Comment: I am thick sometimes, your answer is straight-forward and would work perfectly, thanks alot matey... you missed the equals though :D

Comment: @kyle upsy xD yeah I wrote return first and then replaced it with the variable name - glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PEAR package for validating international telephone numbers](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.validate.validate-au.validate-au.phonenumber.php).

Comment: useful to know, although not an answer to this particular question.